# Is it possibile have different files in different desktop?

Tags: filesystem, spaces

i'm new with mac, the multiple "space/desktop" function is very cool, but it would be better if i could have different files and folder on each of my space.

For example, i want to set up a space for programming works only, and put on desktop only related to this task files. can i ? is there a way to do it?

Comment: On the surface, it isn't setup to easily do this. Desktops are very app-centric, and not file-centric. I'm not saying there isn't a way to rig it, though. However, I think using a Desktop as a folder of itself, may not be the best organization tool. Instead perhaps it would be better to put the programming folder (with all the projects inside) on the Finder sidebar?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is ... i'm using iDesktop https://apps.apple.com/de/app/idesktop/id450986437?mt=12
You can handle your different desktops like workshells ... very comfortably switchable with shortcuts ... the amount of dts is nearly unlimited and at least ... very important ... it is still working in Monterey environment.

Good luck :)